# What is the purpose of groups in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

The VHDL standard defines `groups`, for example:

```vhdl
group Variable_group is ( variable, variable );
```

What are these groups used for? From what I could find on the internet, the only use-case for this language feature is to have attributes defined on a group instead of a single entity. Will these attributes then be defined on all of the elements of a group or are they only defined on the group itself? What is a real-world use-case of a group?

Comment: Do you have a use model for this?   I have never seen it used.

Comment: I haven't seen a use case either that's why I asked. The only thing that seems to justify the existence of groups is being able to assign multiple attributes at once. But other than that, I unfortunately have no use case.